# How to style Magento Global Messages with bootstrap

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add `bootstrap` `alert` with `close` button class to `Magento Global Messages`.
I style these messages with default magento classes, but i want to add bootstrap classes to these messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php`. Find

```
$html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
```

Replace With

```
 $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="alert alert-success messages">';
```

also Find

```
$html .= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg">';
```

and replace with

```
$html .= '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg">';
```